# Do-while loop not running properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with Excel VBA coding.

I want to make one coding may copy data from one sheet to another sheet with certain conditions. Data in cells are only `0` or `1`.

Data in Sheet1 has nearly a thousand rows. I just want to take 15 random rows of data from Sheet1 to Sheet 2. The criteria which must be fulfilled is that each column contains *at least 2 or 3 ones* (`1`). I think the coding is correct, but when it executes, the data does not stop from running. How can I solve this problem?

[image: this current data generate]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Randomize 'Initialize Random number seed 'for sheet 1
Dim MyRows() As Integer    ' Declare dynamic array.
Dim numRows As Integer
Dim percRows As Integer
Dim nxtRow As Integer
Dim nxtRnd As Integer
Dim chkRnd As Integer
Dim copyRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim clmttl1 As Integer
Dim r As Integer

Dim k As Integer
Dim clmttl2 As Integer
Dim ClmTtl As Integer

numRows = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Get 20% of that number
   percRows = 15

Dim claimTotalCheck As Boolean

claimTotalCheck = True
    Do While claimTotalCheck
        ReDim MyRows(percRows)
        For nxtRow = 1 To percRows
getNew:
            'Generate Random number
            nxtRnd = Int((numRows) * Rnd + 1)

            'Loop through array, checking for Duplicates
            For chkRnd = 1 To nxtRow
                'Get new number if Duplicate is found
                If MyRows(chkRnd) = nxtRnd Then GoTo getNew
            Next
            'Add element if Random number is unique
            MyRows(nxtRow) = nxtRnd
        Next

        For copyRow = 1 To percRows
            Sheets(1).Rows(MyRows(copyRow)).Copy _
            Destination:=Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, 1)

        Next

        claimTotalCheck = False
        i = 1

        Do While i < 43
            ClmTtl = 0

            For copyRow = 1 To percRows
                ClmTtl = ClmTtl + Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, i).Value
            Next

            If ClmTtl < 2 Then
                claimTotalCheck = True
            End If
            i = i + 3
        Loop

        k = 2
        Do While k < 43
            clmttl1 = 0

            For copyRow = 1 To percRows
                clmttl1 = clmttl1 + Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, k).Value
            Next

            If clmttl1 < 3 Then
                claimTotalCheck = True
            End If
            k = k + 3
        Loop

        j = 3
        Do While j < 43
            clmttl2 = 0

            For copyRow = 1 To percRows
                clmttl2 = clmttl2 + Sheets(2).Cells(copyRow, j).Value
            Next

            If clmttl2 < 2 Then
                claimTotalCheck = True
            End If
            j = j + 3
        Loop
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) _"The criteria which must be fulfilled is that each column contain at least 2 or 3. "_: where is this criteria to be found in your shown code?  2) what does _"at least 2 or 3"_ mean? Do you mean  _"at least 2"_ or _"2 or 3"_?

Comment: okay. you can look at my coding when I set i,j,k if I not mistaken. column i and j I set atleast 2 while K atleast 3. @user3598756

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847869/do-while-loop-in-excel-vba-error ? Was your problem solved there? If so why didn't you accept any answer?

Comment: I have just generated a sheet with over 1000 rows and 43 columns (as that appears to be the same as the data you are working with and have run your code 12 times  - each time the main do loop (do while claimTotalCheck) ran a single time

Do you actually have data in all 43 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have 43 columns. Please change beggings of `Do While` loops, for example:

```
Do While i < 43
```

to

```
Do While i < Sheets(2).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

and the same for `k` and `j`.

Comment: It may be that there are 43 columns of data BUT 1 or more of those columns may not contain enough 1's to ever meet the stated criteria.

Or it could just be the simple fact that as it is a random selection it is being unlucky enough to never pick rows which will ensure the columns each meet the stated criteria